# receiver for a multi-user communication

Tags: digital-communications

I have an asynchronous multi-user communication with $10$ users. With a matched filter, I see the average BER by user is small ($<0.08$).

Do you know any methods that can reduce the BER by user on reception? I know the multi-user detection but I don't want to estimate the different channels.

Comment: hm, from the top of my head, all you can do to decrease the multi-user interference would be giving your receiver information about how these users differ: and that's exactly that, per-user channel state information, used for multi-user detection. So, you *need* a multi-user detector, but *don't want* a multi-user detector. Why?

Comment: wait, you *are* aware of successive-cancellation decoding, right?

Comment: If you know the timing and codes of all the users, then you can check out the decorrelator. It requires only timing and code information for all users